# Variable-length look-behinds

Tags: ruby, regex

Okay here's my regex to match fish and frog unless fish or frog is preceded by cat

```
/(?<!cat\s)f(ish|rog)/
```

strings:

```
foo catfish       # match fish (want total non-match)
fooxcat fish      # total non-match (yay)
foo cat frog      # total non-match (yay)
foo cat    fish   # match fish (want total non-match)
foo cat    frog   # match frog (want total non-match)
foo dog fish frog # match fish and frog (yay)
fooxfish          # match fish (yay)
foo frog          # match frog (yay)
```

As you can see, the regex works perfectly unless there is zero or more than one whitespace characters between cat and frog/fish. So logically, adding zero or more whitespace characters to my negative look-behind should fix this:

```
/(?<!cat\s*)f(ish|rog)/
```

Unfortunately variable length look behinds are invalid.

**How do I translate the above into a valid regex**, or is there a gem that will allow me to use variable length look-behinds?

(updated frog to rog)

Failed Attempts:

- [`(?<!cat\s)f(ish|rog)`](http://rubular.com/r/9QJTcKKDBh) (first attempt)
- [`cat\s*f(?:ish|rog)|(f(?:ish|rog))`](http://rubular.com/r/JuwUYSRauW) (nope)
- [`cat\s*f(?:ish|rog)|(f(?:ish|rog))`](http://rubular.com/r/L2P1QerL90) (nope)
- [`cat\s*f(?:ish|rog)\K|f(?:ish|rog)`](http://rubular.com/r/EvayzMPtTG) (**This one is so close**, unfortunately it also matches preceding whitespace after each fish/frog)

Comment: `f(ish|frog)` would be `f(ish|rog)`

Comment: How about `str != /\bcat\b/ && str[/\b(:?fish|frog)\b/]`. That simplifies and also checks for 'cat' anywhere in the string (which is what you said you want to do in your first sentence).

Comment: @CarySwoveland sorry, meant preceded by cat

Comment: Here's one I tried: `(?<=\w(?<!cat)|[^\w\s]|^)\s*\Kf(?:ish|rog)` Can test on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qR9kD4/1) or [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/BHhq8CqXIN). It should give accurate matches. Not sure if works for all your cases :]

Comment: @Jonny5 thanks, in future im going to match and stripout whitespace with `gsub!` but great work!

Comment: @JayTarka thanks and welcome! probably more efficient to use gsub yea :]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use alternation operator.

```
cat\s*f(?:ish|rog)|(f(?:ish|rog))
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yJ2hW5/1)

```
string.scan(/cat\s*f(?:ish|rog)|(f(?:ish|rog))/)
```

Comment: or `cat\s*f(?:ish|rog)\K|f(?:ish|rog)`

Comment: isn't this a bit repetitive? Or is the DRY principal a bit different with regex, as repetition allows matching to be more efficient or something?

Comment: upvote for \K....... Jay, there's something you should know about @Avinash. He's a regex pro. Whenever a Ruby regex question is posted, he's there within seconds. He then disappears, waiting for the next one. I don't know how he does it.

Comment: @CarySwoveland hahaha okay

Comment: @CarySwoveland  I love to write answers because of people like you motivating the answerers.

Comment: @AvinashRaj hey, unfortunately your matches aren't quite getting it when I put them through a ruby regex engine (I think you're using a php one according to your demo) anyway I've added links to what I'm seeing to my question

Comment: @JayTarka Use the last one and then remove the empty strings from the returned array.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple more approaches.

First, for testing:

```
def test
  result =
  [
    ['foo catfish',       false], 
    ['fooxcat fish',      false],
    ['foo cat frog',      false],
    ['foo cat    fish',   false],
    ['foo cat    frog',   false],
    ['foo dog fish frog', true ],
    ['fooxfish',          true ],
    ['foo frog cat',      true ],
  ].find { |str, res| check_it(str) != res }
  result ? (puts result; false) : true
end
```

**#1 A most simple regex**

```
def check_it(str)
  word = str[/cat|fish|frog/] 
  word && word != 'cat'
end

test #=> true
```

`'cat'` must be first!

**#2 Divide and conquer**

```
def check_it(str)
  off = (str =~ /cat/)
  off = str.size unless off 
  !!(str[0, off] =~ /fish|frog/)
end

test #=> true
```